# Create a list of numbers of Fibonacci series using for loop

Tags: php, loops, for-loop

Is there any way to produce this with a for loop?
And I tested like this code below but not working well

```php
for ($a = 1; $a <= 1; $a++) {
   echo $a;
   if ($a == 1) {
      echo $a++;
   }
}
```

The expected output is: `1 1 2 3 5 8 13 21 34`

Answer (score 1):

Yes there is and its simple.

```php
for (
    $a = 0, $b = 1, $c = 0; 
    <your cond>; 
    $a = $b, $b = $c
) {
   echo ($c = $a + $b)
}

output 1 1 2 3 5 8 13 21 34 ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Your for loop doesn't comply for the fibonacci sequence because you just do `$a++` which is incrementing the variable by just 1.

To output the sequence, you need to keep track of 2 variables, say `prev` and `curr` and add previous 2 numbers to get the new number and update `prev` accordingly. Below code outputs first 10 numbers of the fibonacci sequence.

```
<?php

$prev = 0;
$curr = 1;

for ($a = 1; $a <= 10; $a++) {
   echo $curr, " ";
   $curr = $curr + $prev;
   $prev = $curr - $prev;
}
```

**Demo:** https://3v4l.org/LMun2

Answer (score 0):

`fibonacci` series using for loop:

```
function GetFibSeries($num){
    $first=0;$second=1;
    for($i=0;$i<$num;$i++){
        if($i<=1){
            $next=$i;
        }  else  {
            $next=$first+$second;
            $first=$second;
            $second=$next;
        }

        echo  $next." ";
    }   
}

GetFibSeries(10);
```

Change `$num` to get desired numbers of the series

Output: 0 1 1 2 3 5 8 13 21 34